# ASP.NET Core - React: Failed to proxy the request to http://localhost:3000/, because the request to the proxy target failed

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core, deployment

I'm developing a website using both ASP.NET Core and ReactJS.

When developing I haven't had any issue with the local machine running the app, nevertheless, when trying to deploy on a server, using the default SPA code that the template provides isn't working correctly since the website gives me the following error:

> [HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:3000)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZkBz.png)

I have seen that the error could be solved if using `spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:xxxx/")` but it didn't work.

My `Startup.cs` looks as follows:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });

        //services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "rx3-front/build";
        });

        services.Configure<StripeSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Stripe"));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = (Configuration.GetSection("Stripe")["SecretKey"]);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors(builder => builder
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
            .AllowCredentials()
        );

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "rx3-front";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                //spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000/");
            }
        });

        //Custom method for initializing the database Roles and setting an unique Admin User
        CreateRoles(serviceProvider).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

I think it is also worth to highlight that before any deployment, I did run `npm run build` so it does make the bundle for the corresponding publish, just in case it did something but then again it did nothing different than giving me a headache.

Any lead where I can start working this around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon creating a new project for comparison and reading line by line, I stumbled upon a tiny change made in the `*.csproj file` that caused the error, where changing the SpaRoot tag value, required a \ at the end of the new value.

`Project1.csproj:`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
     <!-- Please note that at the end of ClientApp (being the name of the folder for the front-end) there's a backwards slash  -->
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
</PropertyGroup>
```

A simple typo but thankfully it was only that.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved a similar issue by downgrading node/npm to match the versions my colleagues are using.

Answer (score 0):

My issue involved ClientApp\devcert.pfx expiring.
I was using Vite, so I deleted devcert.pfx, went into ViteHelper.cs and changed the port to something weird so the if statement would hit (I used 33333), then ran the app, and it recreated the cert.

```
    public static void UseViteDevelopmentServer(this ISpaBuilder spa, int? port = null, string sourcePath = null)
    {

        // throw error if node.js not installed.
        EnsureNodeJSAlreadyInstalled();

        // Default HostingPort
        if (!port.HasValue)
            **port = 3000;**

        spa.Options.DevServerPort = port.Value;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourcePath))
            spa.Options.SourcePath = sourcePath;
        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(spa.Options.SourcePath))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ISpaBuilder.Options.SourcePath", "Must specific Spa Client App path");


        var devServerEndpoint = new Uri($"https://localhost:{spa.Options.DevServerPort}");
        var webHostEnvironment = spa.ApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
        ViteLogger = spa.ApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILoggerFactory>()?.CreateLogger("Vite");

        // If port not in used , launch vite dev server
        if (!CheckPortInUsed(spa.Options.DevServerPort))
        {

            // export dev cert
            var spaFolder = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, spa.Options.SourcePath);
            if (!Directory.Exists(spaFolder))
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(spaFolder);

            var viteConfigPath = GetViteConfigFile(spaFolder);

            var devCert = Path.Combine(spaFolder, "devcert.pfx");
            var serverOptionFile = Path.Combine(spaFolder, $"serverOption{new FileInfo(viteConfigPath).Extension}");


            // Check dev pfx exist
            if (!File.Exists(serverOptionFile) || !File.Exists(devCert))
            {
                var pwd = CreateCertPfxKey(devCert);

                // Create serverOption file
                File.WriteAllText(serverOptionFile, BuildServerOption(devCert, pwd));
                ViteLogger?.LogInformation($"Creating Vite config: {serverOptionFile}");

                InjectionViteConfig(viteConfigPath, serverOptionFile);
            }


            EnsureNodeModuleAlreadyInstalled(spa.Options.SourcePath);

            // launch Vite development server
            RunDevServer(spa.Options.SourcePath, spa.Options.DevServerPort, spa.Options.StartupTimeout);
        }

        spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer(devServerEndpoint);
    }
```