# Failed to proxy the request to 'host' error while running Vuejs from ASP.NET Core

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, .net-core, vuejs2

I have an ASP.NET Core project with a vuejs (2) frontend. It was working fine in the development environment but I left it for a while now I'm trying to modify some modules but every time I run the project, I get this error:

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Failed to proxy the request to http://127.0.0.1:8080/, because the request to the proxy target failed. Check that the proxy target server is running and accepting requests to http://127.0.0.1:8080/

This is my `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
            config.module.rule('vue').uses.delete('cache-loader');
            config.module.rule('js').uses.delete('cache-loader');
            config.module.rule('ts').uses.delete('cache-loader');
            config.module.rule('tsx').uses.delete('cache-loader');
        }
    },
    // ...other vue-cli plugin options...
    pwa: {
        name: 'my site',
        themeColor: '#4DBA87',
        msTileColor: '#000000',
        appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
        appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'black',

        // configure the manifest options
        manifestOptions: {
            display: 'landscape',
            background_color: "#42B883"
            // ...
        },

        // configure the workbox plugin
        workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
        workboxOptions: {
            // swSrc is required in InjectManifest mode.
            swSrc: 'src/registerServiceWorker.js',
            // ...other Workbox options...
        }
    },
    devServer: {
        host: 'localhost',
        proxy: 'mydomain'
    },
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                prependData: `
                @import "@/styles/_vars.scss";
                @import "@/styles/_mixins.scss";
                @import "@/styles/_functions.scss";
                @import "@/styles/_public.scss";
                @import "@/styles/_reset.scss";
                @import "@/styles/_buttons.scss";
                @import "@/styles/_typography.scss";
                @import "@/styles/_alerts.scss";
                @import "@/styles/_rtl.scss";
               `
        }
    }
},

runtimeCompiler: true,
};
```

This is my startup class:

```
using CubesFramework.Security;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Quartz;
using SacoContextLib.Extensions;
using SacoEntitiesLib.Shared;
using ShipmentsContext;
using ShipmentsWEB.Configurations;
using ShipmentsWEB.Extensions;
using ShipmentsWEB.Hubs;
using ShipmentsWEB.Services;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using VueCliMiddleware;

namespace ShipmentsWEB
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            CurrentEnvironment = env;
        }

        public IScheduler Scheduler;
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IWebHostEnvironment CurrentEnvironment { get; set; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // code

            // spa files
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
                     {
                         configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
                     });
            // code
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            // code

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            app.AddStaticFilesOptions(env);
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.AddBLsSecurity(env);

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute
                        (name: "ApiRoute",
                         pattern: "api/{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
                    endpoints.MapHub<ShipmentsHub>("/shipmentshub");
                    endpoints.MapHub<NewsHub>("/newshub");
                });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
                {
                    if (env.IsDevelopment())
                        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                    else
                        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp/dist";

                    if (env.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        spa.UseVueCli("serve");
                    }
                });
        }

        private void OnShutdown()
        {
            Scheduler.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change the middleware to be like this :

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
        else
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp/dist";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:8080");
        } 
   });
```

but the error wasn't solved

Comment: Can this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70548063/asp-net-core-react-failed-to-proxy-the-request-to-http-localhost3000-bec) solved your issue.

Comment: it already exists in my csproj file